# Python custom module not found after running DockerFile

Tags: docker, flask

I am new to Docker and am currently having issues importing local python files into my Flask application using a Dockerfile

File hierarchy:

- survey_tool

  - cli

    - survey_input.py
  - web

    - app.py

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY cli /app
COPY web /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

In my application, I am trying to run a method from another python file (called gui_prompt).
When I try to build the app, the app immediately crashes and gives me this stack trace when running the docker logs file on the container id:

```
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cli.survey_input import gui_prompt
ImportError: No module named cli.survey_input
```

Am I not importing the cli folder correctly?

Comment: make sure you have `__init__.py` file in module folders

Comment: Not a docker expert but I have a feeling you're copying the contents of `cli` and `web` and not the directories to `/app`. Relevant text from [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) 

    If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

    Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.